# I want to create a Microsoft Teams channel for GraphApi from my local host using the password and email address of the surrogate user

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to create a Microsoft Teams channel for GraphApi from my local host using the password and email address of the surrogate user.

I would like to create a channel from GraphApi using Microsoft email and password credentials from an unauthenticated localhost server.

[Development environment]
・local host
・ Nodejs
・ Lib (@azure / ms-rest-nodeauth)

[code]

```
const userName = process.env["SYSTEM_USERNAME"];
const passWord = process.env["SYSTEM_PASSWORD"];
const applicationTokenCredentials = await loginWithUsernamePasswordWithAuthResponse(
    userName,
    passWord,
    {tokenAudience: 'https://graph.microsoft.com'}
);
const accessToken = (await applicationTokenCredentials.credentials.getToken()).accessToken;
//addChannelsMember
const teams_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const channel_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const user_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const res = await fetch(
    `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/${teams_id}/channels/${channel_id}/members`, 
    {
        headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`, 'Content-Type': "application/json"},
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "roles": ["owner"],
            "user@odata.bind": `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('${user_id}')`
        })
    }
);
```

[error]

```
 {
        error: {
            'Unauthorized',
            message: 'Caller does not have the required permissions for accessing this API. AllowedPermissions:'ChannelMember.ReadWrite.All'',
            innerError: {
            date: '2021-02-12T09:06:37',
            'request-id': 'f6bee689-6800-4ee8-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'client-request-id': 'f6bee689-6800-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
        }
    }
```

please help me!

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error message has clearly indicated the cause of your error, you lack the **ChannelMember.ReadWrite.All** permission.

Go to **Azure portal**>**Azure AD**>**App registrations**>**your app**>**API permissions**. Then add the ChannelMember.ReadWrite.All permission, and grant **admin consent** for this permission.

[image]

Comment: Mr.Carl Zhao

Thank you for your reply.

I understand that I need additional permission for Microsoft Graph from the Azure AD app.

However, when I tried to use it from Localhost, the app name was "Microsoft Azure CLI", and I could not find the corresponding app from Azure AD.

I can't find it by searching with appId.

In this case, where should I grant the "ChannelMember.ReadWrite.All" permission?

Comment: @Sho  Is the application not in your tenant? Why can't it be searched?